# How do I run UNet segmentation model in Javascript using tensorflow JS?

Tags: javascript, image-segmentation, tensorflow.js

I had a UNet model which I trained using Python. I saved the **complete** model as `Model.h5` file.

According to tensorflow JS documentations - [How to import a keras model](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras) I converted the model using the `tensorflowjs_converter` tool. Now I have a `Model.json` and bunch of shard files.

My question is, How do I use this model in a Javascript File to perform segmentation on Image?

I managed to load the model and print the model summary in the console, here's the code I used for that:

```
async function app() {
    
   model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_JSON_PATH);
   model.summary();
}
```

This is the model summary from browser console:

```
Layer (type)                    Output shape         Param #     Receives inputs                   
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [null,1024,1024,3]   0                                            
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       [null,1026,1026,3]   0           input_1[0][0]                    
conv1 (Conv2D)                  [null,512,512,32]    864         conv1_pad[0][0]                  
.... <Many more layers here> ....
Total params: 6315522
Trainable params: 6298882
Non-trainable params: 16640
```

So the model seems to be loaded perfectly.

Now say I have an Image on my webpage in an `img` tag. How do I pass that Image to my model, and receive the output? I've seen `tf.browser.fromPixels` but not sure how to proceed.

Any help / pointers to such examples will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HTH:

```js
const img = document.getElementById(elementID);
const tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img); // creates tensor from image element
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(MODEL_JSON_PATH); // load your model
const res = model.predict(tensor); // or model.execute(tensor) // run model
tf.dispose(tensor); // dispose input tensor
const data = await res.arraySync(); // download results from tensor into standard array
tf.dispose(res); // dispose results tensor
console.log(data);
```

*UPDATED*

> Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape [null,1024,1024,3] but got array with shape [512,512,3]

```js
const resized = tf.resizeBilinear(tensor, [1024, 1024]);
const expanded = tf.expandDims(resized, 0);
...
```

Comment: I know I'm late but when I use this, I get the error : `Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape [null,1024,1024,3] but got array with shape [512,512,3].` Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: I've edited answer to include that...